# sidebar and navbar are not being rendered if the page is not refreshed

Tags: angular

In the below code, sidebar and navbar are not being rendered if the page is not refreshed.
Component Code is listed below.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from "@angular/router";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-layout',
    templateUrl: './layout.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./layout.component.css']
})
export class LayoutComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private _router : Router) { }
    IsLoggedIn : boolean = false;
    ngOnInit() {
    if(localStorage.getItem('currentUserId')) this.IsLoggedIn = true;
  }
}
```

HTML code is listed below

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <app-navbar *ngIf="IsLoggedIn==true"></app-navbar>
    <app-sidebar *ngIf="IsLoggedIn==true"></app-sidebar>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <app-second-menu *ngIf="IsLoggedIn==true"></app-second-menu>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: whe do you set the `currentUserId` in localStorage?

Comment: try using *ngIf="IsLoggedIn" ....adn yes when do you set the currentUserId in the localStorage

Comment: If the credentials entered by the user are correct and validated by the server, then I set the currentUserId

Comment: At first the login view is being displayed without navbar and sidebar. Once the user details are validated, I set the currentUserId. But the navbar and sidebar are not being rendered.